# CV format: space

Tags: cv

I modified a CV template (I guess I found it on this website). My MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, xcolor, lipsum, bibentry}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}

\title{\bfseries\Huge My name}
\author{\large{\textbf{\textit{October, 2016}}}}
\date{}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.85\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\vspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
\footnotesize
Department of XXXX\\
University of XXX\\
Address address
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
\footnotesize
Phone: 123456789\\
Email: 123456789\\
Web: myname.com 
\end{minipage}
\vspace{20pt}

\section*{Personal}
Date of Birth: XX/XX/XXXX\\[5pt]
Citizenship: XXXXXXX

\section*{Academic Positions}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2014--\textit{today}&{\bf Associate Professor of XXXXX}\\
&Department of Economics - University of XXXXX\\[5pt]
2006--2014&{\bf Assistant Professor of XXXXX- \textit{with tenure}}\\
&Department of Economics - University of XXXXX\\[5pt]
2002--2006&{\bf Assistent Professor of XXXXX}\\
&Department of Economics - XXXXX\\[5pt]
\end{tabular}

\section*{Visiting Positions}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2010--2016&{\bf Visiting Lecturer}\\
&School of Economics \& Management - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\[5pt]
2011&{\bf Visiting Scholar}\\
&Fox Business School - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\[5pt]
2008&{\bf Visiting Scholar}\\
&Fox Business School - XXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Other Academic Positions}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2015--\textit{today}&{\bf Research Center in XXXXXXX \& XXXXXXXXXX-- Director}\\
&Department of Economics - University of Messina\\[5pt]
2010--\textit{today}&{\bf M.Sc. in XXXXXXXXX -- Board Member}\\
&Department of Economics - University of XXXXXXXX\\[5pt]
2015--\textit{today}&{\bf \textit{Post Lauream} Course in XXXXXXXX -- Board Member }\\
&Department of Economics - University of Messina\\[5pt]
2013--\textit{today}&{\bf Ph.D. in Economics, Management \& Statistics --  Board Member}\\
&Department of Economics - University of XXXXXXXXX\\[5pt]
2015&{\bf Ph.D. in Economics, Management \& Statistics -- Director}\\
&Department of Economics - University of XXXXXXXX\\[5pt]
\end{tabular}

\section*{Education}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2008&{\bf Ph.D. in Economics, XXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\
&\textit{Supervisor}: Prof. XXXXXXXX \\
& \textit{Thesis title}: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
& \textit{Ph.D. Committe}: Prof. XXXXXXX (internal); Prof. XXXXXXXX (external)\\[5pt]
2008&{\bf Ph.D. in XXXXXXXXXXX, University of XXXXXXX}\\
&\textit{Supervisor}: Prof. XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
& \textit{Thesis title}: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
& \textit{Ph.D. Committe}: Prof. XXXXXXXXX; Prof. XXXXXXX\\[5pt]
2000&{\bf M.Sc. in Economics, University of XXXXXXXXXX}\\
&\textit{Supervisor}: Prof. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
& \textit{Dissertation title}: XXXXXXXXXXXXX\\[5pt]
1998&{\bf B.Sc. in XXX, University of XXXXXXXXXX}\\
&\textit{Supervisor}: Prof. XXXXXX \\
& \textit{Dissertation title}: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\[5pt]
\end{tabular}

\section*{Research Project}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2016&{\bf XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\
&\textit{Principal Investigators}: Prof. XXXXXXXXXXXXX \\
& Department of Economics -- University of XXXXXXXX\\[5pt]
2005--2009&{\bf XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX}\\
&\textit{Principal Investigators}: Prof. XXXXXX \& XXXXXXX \\
& XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXX -- XXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Scholarships}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2000&XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
1999&XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Research Interests}
XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX.

\section*{Publications}
\subsection*{\it Books}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2014&XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXX. \emph{XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX}, XXXXXXX XXXXX XXX.\\
\end{tabular}

\subsection*{\it Chapters in Books}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2015&XXXXXXX XXX X XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\emph{XXXXX XXXXXXx XXXXXXXXXX}, XXXXXXXXXXX XX.\\[5pt]
2012&XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX  \emph{XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX X}, XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX.\\[5pt]
&XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX  \emph{XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX X}, XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX.\\
\end{tabular}

\subsection*{\it Articles}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2016&XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX  \emph{XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX X}, XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX. \\[5pt]
&XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX  \emph{XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX X}, XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX. \\[5pt]
&XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX  \emph{XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX X}, XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX. \\[5pt]
2015&XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX  \emph{XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX X}, XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX..\\[5pt]
2013&XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX  \emph{XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX X}, XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX.\\[5pt]
2009&XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX  \emph{XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX X}, XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX.\\[5pt]
2007&XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX  \emph{XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX X}, XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX..\\[5pt]
\end{tabular}

\section*{Teaching (Last 5 years)}
\subsection*{\it Department of Economics--University of XXXXXXXXXXX}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2015--2016&XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX)\\
& \textit{Ph.D. in XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx}\\[5pt]
& XXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX X\\
& \textit{M.Sc. in XXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\[5pt]
& XXXXXXXXXXX\\
& \textit{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\[7 pt]
2014--2015&Microeconomics (Game Theory Module)\\
& \textit{Ph.D. in XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\[5pt]
& Applied Financial Econometrics\\
& \textit{M.Sc. in XXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\[5pt]
& XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx\\
& \textit{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\[5pt]
& XXXXX \& XXXXXXXXXXX\\
& \textit{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\[5pt]
& XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXx\\
& \textit{XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXX}\\[7 pt]
\end{tabular}
\subsection*{\it Department of Economics--University of XXXXXXXXXXX}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2015--2016&XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX)\\
& \textit{Ph.D. in XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx}\\[5pt]
& XXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX X\\
& \textit{M.Sc. in XXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\[5pt]
& XXXXXXXXXXX\\
& \textit{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\[7 pt]
2014--2015&Microeconomics (Game Theory Module)\\
& \textit{Ph.D. in XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\[5pt]
\end{tabular}

\section*{References}
Upon request.


\end{document}
```

As you may notice in pp. 1, 3 and 4, a large space is left after section "Visiting Position" (p.1), subsections "Chapter in Books" (p.3) and Articles (p.4).

I tried to use the `\vspace` command, but I could not get any improvement. Is there any tip you can suggest me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `minipage` does not have ` [ht]` argument.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: you get _lots_ of warnings `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 125--125` note 10000 is _maximum_ badness.

Comment: How can I solve it? I used minipage to include some information below my name.

Comment: There is a space but you do not say what you want to happen, you have set all your lists as `tabular` so they are unbreakable boxes, there is no room for the next section so latex has no choice but to break the page at that point.

Comment: I do not like those spaces. So it seems that I should change template?

Comment: Thanks. I removed [ht], which in fact did not add anything. I got your point...since latex cannot break tabular....if a tabular fits in a page...fine. Otherwise it poses the new box in a new page

Comment: you could change to longtable (which do break) with very little changes

Comment: You mean longtable instead of tabular?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried with longtable and it works. However, I cannot find out how I can maintain the split in subsections. I generate a longtable after the section pubblication. What happens is that, for instance, books, chapter in books etc. go on the left just above the year of publication.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Done. I managed to work it out. Thanks a lot David. Always helpful.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you want to add an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B I think it's a duplicate of any "how do I allow page breaks in tables" question. I'll find one